# Нажатие на ссылку TWebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi, html, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь, мучаю TWebBrowser чтобы он мне отдавал `innerText` у ссылки при клике.

Нарыл пока только вариант, совмещающий JavaScript, который изменяет текст статуса, а затем `event:onStatusTextChange` дает нам собственно текст.

Т.е. у меня есть JavaScript:

```
function statusChange(text) {
    window.status = text;
}
```

В программе это выглядит:

```
procedure TMain.webBrowserStatusTextChange(Sender: TObject;
  const Text: WideString);
var
  t: String;
begin
  if pos('CMD:', Text) > 0 then
    begin
      t := Text;
      delete(t, 1, 4);
      reMessage.Text := t;
    end;
end;
```

А вот и сама ссылка:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:statusChange(''CMD:'+Text+'''); return false;">Текст</a>
```

Но не получается сие сделать, так как постоянно возвращается пустая строка или `about:blank#`. Что делаю не так? Имеется ли возможность это сделать как-то по-другому?

**UPD**

Ссылка вырвана из контекста программы, поэтому вам странным кажется количество кавычек.

```
Link := '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:statusChange(''CMD:'+Text+'''); return false;">Текст</a>'
```

Двойная кавычка в Delphi - заменяет экранирование символа. И по той же причине (моя ошибка в вопросе) вы не поняли, что такое `Text` ибо это переменная программы, а не скрипта. По сути, после ссылка будет иметь вид:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:statusChange('CMD:Текст'); return false;">Текст</a>
```

Т.е. как вы и написали, можно заменить на `innerText`. Но проблема не в этом, это работает замечательно все, а вот статусы, возвращаемые через событие TWebBrowser всегда при нажатии возвращают текст: `about:blank#`.

**UPD2**

```
procedure TMain.webBrowserBeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
var
  p: integer;
begin
  p := pos('CMD:', URL);
  if p > 0 then
    ShowMessage(copy(URL, p+4, Length(URL)-p-3));
end;

procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser.Navigate('http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test.html');
end;
```

На выходе ваша страничка с программой и ни единого всплывающего сообщения.

Comment: Эээ а вы уверены, что window.status - это то же самое, что TWebBrowser.statusText? o_O В общем, ща попробую по-другому решить) Я просто протестил и он выдавал мне все состояния именно *браузера* (соединение, чтение данных и пр.), но не свойство объекта window.

Comment: Да быть же не может)) На ссылки нажимали? + Версия Делфи какая? У меня 7.

Comment: Уже лучше) Ну, тогда надо искать принципиальное различие между ссылками, по логике. Кстати, документ у вас полный? Имеется в виду, доктайп, кодировка указана, теги (html, head, body) на месте? Из-за этого периодически мистика происходит.

Comment: А вот об этой мистике я не подумал. Ща поправим доктайп

Comment: Неа, доктайп, html, head, body все на месте.

    v[0] := '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">';
    v[0] := v[0] + '<html><head><script language="JavaScript">function delphiRequest(text) { window.location = ''#CMD:''+text; return false; }</script></head><body style="margin: 0 0 0 0;"><div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div></body></html>';

Думаю, что проблема в том, что я динамически добавляю элементы и они почему-то не появляются в тексте HTML.

Comment: Думал и об этом. Но понимаете, оно же работает! Но, когда меняешь `title`. Вообще кто бы подкинул компонент, который умеет ссылки, подсветка текста и т.п.
Тем не менее спасибо, буду еще думать.

Comment: Если вы динамически добавляете JS, имейте в виду, что в IE (а в делфи его библиотеки) так не умеет =) То есть вы можете сделать в ресурсах или папке с программой html-файл, в котором будет весь JS, и в него уже что-то динамически добавлять. Я вот только что добился вашего результата (переход и текст `blank#`), функция delphiRequest оказалась не определена. Мне кажется, ваша разгадка где-то здесь)

Компонента, к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Добавьте в ответ и я приму.
Суть в двух разных методах добавления данных на страницу. Первый вроде работает, но криво, второй тоже работает, но из-за того, что в скрипте есть `CMD:` то на первую загрузку веб-браузер тоже реагирует, да и потом ошибки есть, буду искать другое решение.

    //1st
    S := '<html>...</html>';
    webBrowser.Navigate('about:'+S);

    //2nd
    Document := webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
    v[0] := '<html>...</html>';
    Document.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
    Document.Close;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, приму на веру, что смена window.status вызовет `webBrowserStatusTextChange` (времени нет потестить), что увидел сразу:

`onclick` в html обрабатывается примерно так:

```
<a onclick="lalala();ololo();"></a> 
// эквивалентно:
a.onclick = function(){ lalala();ololo(); }
```

, то есть префикс `javascript:` - ошибка. Его используют обычно в виде `href="javascript:lalala();"`, т.е. для передачи кода в адресную строку с последующим переходом-выполнением.

Еще переменная Text у вас не определена, судя по постановке задачи вам нужно свойство innerHTML (в данном случа "Текст") текущей ссылки this.

То есть нужно, как указано в каменте:

```
<a href="#" onclick="statusChange('CMD:'+this.innerHTML);return false;">Текст</a>
```

, либо:

```
<a href="javascript:statusChange('CMD:'+this.innerHTML);">Текст</a>
```

Далее, кавычки, да) возможно, просто не выполняется функция (а судя по решетке в получаемой строке - происходит переход по ссылке и `return false;` не срабатывает).

Далее, просто чуть оптимизации

```
reMessage.Text := copy(Text, 5, Length(Text)-4);
```

Если после всего этого не заработает - пишите наблюдения.

**UPDATE** Изменим подход:

JS:

```
function delphiRequest(text) { window.location = '#CMD:'+text; return false; }
```

ссылка:

```
<a onclick="return delphiRequest(this.innerHTML);">Текст</a>
```

Делфи:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
var p: integer;
begin
  p := pos('CMD:', URL);
  if p > 0 then
    ShowMessage(copy(URL, p+4, Length(URL)-p-3));
end;
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос комментарий.
Что касается вашего способа:

    reMessage.Text := copy(Text, 5, Length(Text)-4);

вы несомненно правы, но это мелочи, на которых я пока решил не останавливаться.

Дело еще в том, что я не знаю бесплатных компонентов, которые бы умели: подсвечивать отдельные слова, выделять ссылки и вставлять изображения, поэтому я выбрал `TWebBrowser` как временное решение.

Comment: Тоже пробовал, почему-то если `Cancel := false` все равно переход совершается.
Сейчас все сделал теми же функциями JavaScript что и до (с небольшими изменениями), но меняю `title`, а соответственно обрабатываю `onTitleChange` кажется, и все работает. Но данные грабли жутко мне не нравятся.

Comment: `Cancel := false` это вы о чем?) Вот я вставил в ответ свой кусок, он прям 100% рабочий) Вы точно все мое скопировали как в ответе? И решетку не забыли перед CMD? 

ЗЫ: Изменение статуса - ровно те же грабли. Я пытаюсь просто наименее заметные сделать)

Comment: И кстати, @Dex, спасибо за вопрос, мостик Delphi->JS я бы еще год собирался сделать без него =)

Comment: Переходит на новую страницу с текстом:

    return delphiRequest(this.innerHTML);

Comment: @Dex, <a href="http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test.html">пробуйте</a>) Там и html-js (смотрите исходник), и текст программы. 

Кстати, BeforeNavigate2 - стандартное событие и в IDE оно первое в списке.

Comment: Я знаю) К счастью, с Дельфой знаком семь лет. Но вот эта задача, почему-то стала сложной для меня. Смотрите **UPD2**